# 'ls' and 'll' are not working in bash linux ldap-nss.c:1319

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

The following error comes up when I 'ls' or 'll' in Linux:

```
ldap-nss.c:1319: do_init: Assertion `cfg->ldc_uris[__session.ls_current_uri] != ((void *)0)' failed.
```

Comment: What do you have `ls` and `ll` aliased to in your shell?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a permissions issue:

```
chmod 644 /etc/ldap.conf
```

Hopefully this saves someone some time somewhere down the line.

Comment: +1 self-answers are good for SO